# How To Upload Laravel with vuejs To Shared Hosting

Tags: laravel

I upload my laravel project in Host domain i work with laravel and vuejs, any easy way to deploy it?

Comment: Can you explain your issue in more detail?

Comment: I wanna upload my Laravel Project Domain Hosting, I work my Project With laravel and vuejs while i upload it in to Host domain i could'nt know how to upload

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the following steps to deploy your Laravel and vue.js application to a shared hosting.

- generate your product vue build using `npm run prod`
- upload all the changes and project to a git repository.
- clone your git repository to your shared hosting, mainly via integrated terminal in some shared hosting or via ssh key access.
- redirect your domain or subdomain directory to `/public` folder.
- run `composer install`
- run `cp .env.example .env`
- setup `.env` files according to database configuration and emails etc.
- run `php artisan migrate`
- run `php artisan key:generate`
- run `php artisan storage:link` if you want media uploading to your server.